# Can I have multiple mx records for a domain

Tags: dns-zone

I have a domain and I want that if one mx record fails then 2nd mx should takeover for sending and receiving mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fallback MX is pretty standard. Run `dig mx gmail.com` and you'll see an example.

However, there is often no real need for it, because mail servers queue mail for a few days anyway, and there are extra problems you'll introduce having a fallback, one being that it's always hit harder by spammers, because its security it often less stringent.